# Cannot locate search bar with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have been trying to locate a sidebar bar in this website https://covid19.who.int/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIkoua643_6gIVDNd3Ch3qgApPEAAYASAAEgIfIvD_BwE

The search bar I am trying to locate is the one on top, which says "Search by Country, Territory, or Area"
I tried with XPATH but I always get error in locating the element, or sometimes it says that my element is not interactable (I guess that means that I am locating a different element)
Could please show a way to find that element?

[here is what I saw when I inspected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Flbuv.png)

Comment: you are searching for searchbar and sidebar both or only searchbar and what you want to do after locating search bar, I mean what is you end goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to search Country and see the data, So for that you need to locate the `id` of search box(i.e `react-select-2-input`) and enter the Country name using `send_keys` and hit enter.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


site = 'https://covid19.who.int/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIkoua643_6gIVDNd3Ch3qgApPEAAYASAAEgIfIvD_BwE'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'chromedriver.exe') # Here I am using Chrome's web driver
#For Firefox Web driver
#driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'geckodriver.exe') 
driver.get(site)
time.sleep(3)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("react-select-2-input")
elem.send_keys("Brazil")
elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

If you are only interested in locating search-bar then you can locate it by it's id(`driver.find_element_by_id("react-select-2-input")`)

[image]

*How did I find search-bar id?*

Basically search-bar is nothing but a text-box and in HTML text-box code starts with `<input type="text">`, So I had to just find the HTML code of text box in inspect element of browser.

By seeing your screen-shot I can say you were going in right direction, just you had to expand `div` tag more till you find code of text box.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I am very new to this field and even if I know how to code and do the stuff, I really struggle to find the elements... I guess I should start learning HTML seriously. May I ask you how you found that id? I pressed inspect on the bar but I couldn't find... I guess it is a silly question to ask but I am missing something. Thanks

Comment: @L'in first of all no question is silly if you're learning something, now how I found it, you were searching for `search-bar` and i.e nothing but a textbox and in HTML text box starts with `input type text` so I copied the id of that textbox.

Comment: @L'inventore I've added in answer that how did I find search-bar id.